# Differential equation y'(t)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A container contains 1000 liters of fluid. Let $y(t)$ be the ammount of fluid that is left in the tank at a given time $t$ (in hours). A tap on the container is opened, and the phenomenom is modelled by the differential equation:

$$y'(t) +ty=−t,\qquad  y(0) = 1$$

Solve the differential equation how? I dont understand the $y'$ of t part. It is not $y'\cdot t$

Comment: $y'(t)$ just means $y'$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y'=-t-ty = -t(1+y)$$ then
$$\dfrac{y'}{y+1}=-t.$$
Integranting
$$\ln|y+1|= - \dfrac{t^2}{2}+C$$
Using the exponential
$$  y= -1+K \exp \left(   - \dfrac{t^2}{2} \right)$$
Using the initial condition
$$1=y(0)=-1+K \Rightarrow K=2.$$
The solution is
$$  y= -1+2\exp \left(   - \dfrac{t^2}{2} \right)$$

Comment: Great! Thank you, i understood it completely now

Comment: You're welcome!